# convert mysql query to jpa query

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

how to convert below MySQL query to Jpa query.

MySQL query :

```
SELECT s FROM supplier as s where s.id like '%s%' or s.reg_no like '%s%' or 
s.first_name like '%s%' or s.last_name like '%s%';
```

I am trying to do it. but I am getting error.

**Edit :**  
If there would have been one parameter it can be done like below method.

```
List<Supplier> findSuppliersByRegNoContaining(String regNo);
```

but I don't know, if it is possible when there are two or more parameter. and pass same value is passed to all the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this in your repository interface

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM supplier as s where s.id like '%s%' or s.reg_no like '%s%' or s.first_name like '%s%' or s.last_name like '%s%' ")
```

another format

```
List<Supplier> getSuppliers();
```

Comment: return type would be List<Supplier>

Comment: '%s%, this "s" should be a parameter how to pass it.

Comment: @Query("SELECT s FROM supplier as s where s.id LIKE CONCAT('%',:param,'%') ")

List<Supplier>  getSuppliers(@Param("param") String param);

Comment: Like wise use multiple parameters

Comment: Madhu Reddy thanks. I tried this before. it not work because I used just % but it should be like that '%'.   this is the answer I expected.

@Query( "SELECT s FROM Supplier as s where s.regNo LIKE CONCAT('%',:param,'%') or s.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%',:param,'%') " +
            " or s.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%',:param,'%') or s.collectingCenter.name LIKE CONCAT('%',:param,'%')" +
            " or s.id LIKE CONCAT('%',:param,'%') " )
    List<Supplier> getSuppliers(@Param( "param" ) String param);